# Why doesn't the second Chern form $C_2$ vanish in 4D Euclidean space?

Tags: tensor-calculus, lie-algebra, topological-field-theory

I know the second Chern form cannot vanish identically, but I can't see what is wrong with a simple reasoning that gets that it vanishes.

Take a standard $SU(N)$ Yang-Mills theory in a 4-dimensional Euclidean space. The second Chern form is defined (up to constant) as $ C_2 = F \wedge F,$ where $F = F^a t_a$, the $F^a$ being two-forms and the $t_a$ forming a basis of the Lie algebra $\frak{su}$$(N)$. The reasoning is the following:
$$ F \wedge F = F^a \wedge F^b [t_a,t_b] \stackrel{1}{=} F^b \wedge F^a [t_a,t_b] \stackrel{2}{=}  -F^b \wedge F^a [t_b,t_a] = -F \wedge F \quad \rightarrow \quad F \wedge F = 0,$$

where in $\stackrel{1}{=}$ I just exchanged the order of the two forms, getting a $(-1)^2=1$ factor, that is, no sign change... and in $\stackrel{2}{=}$ I just exchanged the order of the two matrices in the commutator, picking up a minus sign.

What is wrong with the reasoning above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chern form does not include a commutator. It has a trace instead:
$$
C_2 = -\frac 1 {8\pi^2}{\rm tr}(t_at_b)F^a\wedge F^b.
$$
Note that ${\rm tr}(t_a t_b)={\rm tr}(t_bt_a)$, so it has no reason to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out as soon as I finished writing the question. The obvious problem here is that, for $\omega$ being a Lie algebra-valued form, $\omega \wedge \omega = \omega^a \wedge \omega^b [t_a,t_b]$ is only for k-forms with k odd. We use the fact that the components of the forms anti-commute to take the commutator on the matrices by taking the anti-symmetric part, it is not there from the beginning.